# How to automize loading file in a R script?

Tags: r

I'm trying to automatize some passage of my R work routine. I would like to know if there is a way to automatize that R can load several files contained in a folder one by one and make some operations.

Imagine that within a folder I have 10 files called:

```
Mark_L2.txt
Mark_L5.txt
Michael_L2.txt
Michael_L5.txt
```

Is there a way for R to load all the file with `L2.txt` extension one by one and do some operation than I want to add then like a plot?

```
ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=variable, y=mean)) +geom_bar(aes(fill = ID),position = 'fill',stat="identity")
```

One by one it takes long time..
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like:

```
 files <- list.files("YOUR_FOLDER",pattern = 'L2.txt')
 pdf('YOURPDF.pdf')
    for(i in files){
    file <-read.table(paste0("YOUR_FOLDER/",i))

    ##INSERT OPERATIONS HERE
    my.plot <- ggplot(file) #include other specifications for plot
    print(my.plot)


    }

dev.off()
```

?

Comment: ok YEs it works but not perfectly cause in this way I obtain just 1 plot for the last of my file and no different plots as much as how many files I have in my folder. I mean

for (i in files) {

file <-read.table(paste0("WF/Plots/",i),header=T)

ggplot ...etc...

}

in this way i obtain just 1 plot at the end, while I would like to have different plot for each file L2 i have in my folder....how can i resolve it? thank you a lot!!!!

Comment: the best thing to do, if I understand correctly what you want, is to open a pdf before the for loop: `pdf('PDFNAME.pdf')`.  Then run the loop and build a plot inside the for loop for the given file `my.plot <- ggplot(i)`.  Then print the plot within the for loop: `print(my.plot)`.  After the for loop, run `dev.off()` and it should put all those plots in the pdf.

Comment: Thanks Balter!! it was of great help in this way

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of the `list.files()` method that lists files in a directory. It takes as argument a regular expression pattern, which filters out what you specify. For example `list.files(path = ".", pattern = L2\\.txt)`